# How to determine the size of bias matrices in a neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I'm new to the world of machine learning. My question is how can I determine the size of the biases in a neural network (with backpropagation algorithm)? Currently, I have a 2-layer neural network (1 hidden and 1 output layer). Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

sigmoid = lambda x : 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
dsigmoid = lambda y: y * (1 - sigmoid(y))

# This function performs the given function (func) to the whole numpy array
def mapFunc(array, func) :
    newArray = array.copy()
    for element in np.nditer(newArray, op_flags=['readwrite']) :
        element[...] = func(element)
    return newArray

class NeuralNetwork :

def __init__(self, input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes) :
    self.input_nodes = input_nodes
    self.hidden_nodes = hidden_nodes
    self.output_nodes = output_nodes

    self.W_ih = np.random.rand(hidden_nodes, input_nodes)
    self.W_ho = np.random.rand(output_nodes, hidden_nodes)

    self.B_ih = np.random.rand(hidden_nodes, 1)
    self.B_ho = np.random.rand(output_nodes, 1)

    self.learningRate = 0.1

def predict(self, inputs) :
    # Calculate hidden's output
    H_output = np.dot(self.W_ih, inputs)
    H_output += self.B_ih
    H_output = mapFunc(H_output, sigmoid) # Activation

    # Calculate output's output
    O_output = np.dot(self.W_ho, H_output)
    O_output += self.B_ho
    O_output = mapFunc(O_output, sigmoid) # Activation

    return O_output

def train(self, inputs, target) :
    # Calculate hidden's output
    H_output = np.dot(self.W_ih, inputs)
    H_output += self.B_ih
    H_output = mapFunc(H_output, sigmoid) # Activation

    # Calculate output's output
    O_output = np.dot(self.W_ho, H_output)
    O_output += self.B_ho
    O_output = mapFunc(O_output, sigmoid) # Activation

    # Calculate output error :
    O_error = O_output - target

    # Calculate output delta
    O_gradient = mapFunc(O_output, dsigmoid)
    O_gradient = np.dot(O_gradient, np.transpose(O_error)) * self.learningRate

    W_ho_delta = np.dot(O_gradient, np.transpose(H_output))

    self.W_ho -= W_ho_delta
    self.B_ho -= O_gradient

    # Calculate hidden error :
    W_ho_t = np.transpose(self.W_ho)
    H_error = np.dot(W_ho_t, O_error)

    # Calculate hidden delta :
    H_gradient = mapFunc(H_output, dsigmoid)
    H_gradient = np.dot(H_gradient, np.transpose(H_error)) * self.learningRate

    W_ih_delta = np.dot(H_gradient, inputs)

    self.W_ih -= W_ih_delta
    self.B_ih += H_gradient

    return O_output


n = NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1)

inputs = np.matrix([[1], [0], [1], [1], [0], [1], [0], [0]])

input_list = []
input_list.append([[1], [0]])
input_list.append([[0], [1]])
input_list.append([[1], [1]])
input_list.append([[0], [0]])

target = np.matrix([[0], [0], [1], [1]])

outputs = []
for i in range(50000) :
    ind = np.random.randint(len(input_list))
    inp = input_list[ind]
    out = n.train(inp, target[ind]).tolist()
    outputs.append(out[0][0])

print outputs
plt.plot(outputs)

plt.show()

newInput = [[1], [1]]
print (n.predict(newInput))
```

In the train function, the line `self.B_ih += H_gradient` throws me an error about their sizes not being equal. I even tried to make the biases only a single number but that didn't help as it gets changed by `H_gradient` to a matrix. So, is there something wrong in the bias itself or I did some other step(s) wrong?

Comment: You would want as many bias values as you have neurons in the coming layer.

Comment: @JahKnows But then it doesn't get added to `H_output` because their size becomes different.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your bias is correct. The shape of the gradient being subtracted from the bias in the end should be (2,1) and not (2,2) - which is the problem in your case (shape of H_gradient should not be (2,2)).

Also,

`#Calculate output error :
    O_error = O_output - target`

Here, you should be using mean squared error (cross entropy loss if classifying), and not just the difference.

Lastly, the gradients are calculated separately with respect to the weights and bias. So dL/dW is calculated separately and subtracted from weights, and dL/db is calculated separately and subtracted from the bias (where L is the loss). You're just using the same gradient for both.

Comment: Can you be more specific and tell me how should I change my code? Am I calculating the `H_gradient` wrong? As the size of the gradient is determined by it's calculation